# Finite-dimensional C*-algebra quotient

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional C*-algebra. Is it true that every quotient of $A$ is of the form $PAP$ for some projection $P\in A$?

(It's obviously true for commutative C*-algebras, that's why I am asking.)

Comment: Is it true for commutative algebras? $A = C[0,1]$ has lots of ideals, hence quotients, but has no non-trivial projections. The only things here of the form PAP are $A$ itself and 0 (and not every quotient of $A$ is isomorphic to $A$).

Comment: I mean commutative finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finite-dimensional C*-algebras are of the form $A = \oplus_1^n F_i$ where $F_i = M_{k_i}$ for some $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Its not too hard to convince yourself and that any ideal is of the form $I = \oplus_{i \in J} F_i$ where $J \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$. The quotient is then isomorphic to $A/I \simeq \oplus_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\} \setminus J} F_i$. From here, can you show that $A/I \simeq PAP$ for some projection $P$? (the same argument as finite-dimensional + commutative will work)

Comment: I see, I was thinking about it in a totally wrong way. I thought that $PAP$ must always be a quotient. But that is absolutely not true.